# How to prevent scrolling to the bottom of page when opening a modal that has a form in it with autofocus set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I have a featherlight.js modal set up where when a button is clicked, a modal is opened with a form in it. I've set the first input field in the form to autofocus when the modal is opened. However, whenever the modal is opened, the user is automatically scrolled to the very bottom of the page.

This is because the modal code (including where autofocus is set) is found at the bottom of the page.

Is there a good way to prevent the automatic scrolling?

Comment: maybe the autofocus part is running before the modal is actually displayed...

Comment: @Scaramouche, I don't think so, since on pageload it is fine, but it only scrolls you to the bottom when the modal is launched. Here is my page: https://blackcart.co/stores (click on any of the brand images to launch modal).

Comment: I see this code: `function() {
  $('#bc-modal-store > img').attr('src', $(this).data('img'));
  $('#bc-modal-store > input[type=email]').focus();
  $('#bc-modal-store > button').data('redirectUrl', $(this).data('url'));
}` in `lightbox.js`, maybe you should start looking there, if you could include a minimal example in a snippet in your post, I could help you more

Comment: @Donny care to share some code ?